# display function results as array

Tags: php

I am trying to set array 'status' as function results

```html
<?php
function GetTags(){
 echo "#php, #html";
}

$params = array(
 'status' =>GetTags()
);

print_r ($params);
```

I need array 'status' to be "#php, #html"
Tried a lot of combination with " and ' but without any success
What I am missing here, anybody to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PHP echo and PHP return in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387765/what-is-the-difference-between-php-echo-and-php-return-in-plain-english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the result that you're getting that with your `GetTags()` function you're actually `echo`ing `#php, #html` (which doesn't return anything so you get an empty string in the value). What you need to do is `return` it from the function so it will be added as `status`' value.

Your way:

```
function GetTags() {
    echo "#php, #html";
}

$params = array(
    'status' =>GetTags()
);

print_r ($params);
```

*Result*

> #php, #htmlArray ( [status] => )

Notice how the text is first printed on the screen, and then you get no value in `status`?

Now, `return`ing instead of `echo`ing:

```
function GetTags() {
    return "#php, #html";
}

$params = array(
    'status' =>GetTags()
);

print_r ($params);
```

*Result*

> Array ( [status] => #php, #html )