# Why is PHP producing garbled HTML for my table code?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have created a heatmap function that I am going to use to fill the cells of a table in html using PHP 7.2.

Here is my function:

```
function bg($latency) {
    if ($latency ==0) {echo '#11FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <30) {echo '#22FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <60) {echo '#33FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <90) {echo '#44FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <120) {echo '#55FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <150) {echo '#66FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <180) {echo '#77FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <210) {echo '#88FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <240) {echo '#99FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <270) {echo '#AAFFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency <300) {echo '#BBFFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency >=300) {echo '#CCB27F';} 
}
```

I pull values from a MySQL table with a simple select statement and then try to build the table with the following code snippet:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['origin'].'</td><td bgcolor='.bg($row['lt01']).'>'.$row['lt01'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

But for some reason the output is garbled with the function output appearing before the HTML source:

```
#11FFFF<tr><td>LT01</td><td bgcolor=>0</td></tr>
#22FFFF<tr><td>LT02</td><td bgcolor=>11</td></tr>
#44FFFF<tr><td>LT03</td><td bgcolor=>62</td></tr>
#44FFFF<tr><td>LT04</td><td bgcolor=>74</td></tr>
#99FFFF<tr><td>LT05</td><td bgcolor=>214</td></tr>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `bg` function is echoing the colour code to the screen instead of returning it to be used by your other PHP code. Change the function to use `return` instead of `echo` and it will work as expected.

```
function bg($latency) {
    if ($latency == 0)       {return '#11FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 30)   {return '#22FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 60)   {return '#33FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 90)   {return '#44FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 120)  {return '#55FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 150)  {return '#66FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 180)  {return '#77FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 210)  {return '#88FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 240)  {return '#99FFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 270)  {return '#AAFFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency < 300)  {return '#BBFFFF';} 
    elseif ($latency >= 300) {return '#CCB27F';} 
}
```

`echo` is used when you want to display content to the screen right now. Due to how the PHP parser works, the `echo` in the `bg` function will run before the `echo` that called the function, as the parent `echo` has yet to finish. This is where `return` comes in. Instead of printing the content to the screen right now, it passes it back to whatever called the function to be used in whatever way you wish.

A more detailed explanation on echo vs return can be found in this post: [What is the difference between PHP echo and PHP return in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387765/what-is-the-difference-between-php-echo-and-php-return-in-plain-english)

Comment: Also he is missing the quotes surrounding the bgcolor attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been flagged as a possible duplicate instead? Given the reference link you included at the end.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I suppose it could have been. I wouldn't object to flagging it as such, though the reason as to why I didn't is the OP wasn't directly asking what the differences are between echo and return like the question I liked was.

Comment: @EliasSoares As long as an html attribute's value has no spaces, quotes are not required. See [WhatWG Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) and view the 'Unquoted attribute value syntax' section.