# How to show string in variable funtion PHP

Tags: php

I am  have a code like this:

```
function sampleName(string $name)
{
    echo ", good morning $name" . PHP_EOL;
}

function showName(string $name, $filter): string
{
    return  "Hello" . $filter($name) . PHP_EOL;
}

showName("John", "sampleName") . PHP_EOL;
```

And the result is :

```
, good morning John
```

How to show the `Hello` when i am call `showName()` function?

Comment: `sampleName()` should return the string, not echo it.

Comment: So this is a Typo question right?  I mean, you know how to write the word `return` and you know what it does, you just didn't do it.  This is just a facepalm question, right?  We don't have anything new to teach you here.  You just reversed the `echo` and the `return`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9387765/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Return values from SampleName Function and print return value of ShowName function.

```
function sampleName(string $name)
{
    return ", good morning $name" . PHP_EOL;
}

function showName(string $name, $filter) : string
{
    return "Hello" . $filter($name) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo showName("John", "sampleName") . PHP_EOL;
```

Output : Hello, good morning John

Answer (score 0):

The `showName` function `return`'s which is why the `Hello` part does not show.

You could either `echo` instead of return in the function or echo your call to the function, ie `echo showName('John', 'sampleName');`