# Media elements not showing in correct place when generated by function

Tags: php, html, css

I have two excerpts of code to generate a profile card. The first generates a profile card on a page, and neatly places the images inside a scroller box as shown below.

Working code on profile page

```
  <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo "{$user_data['first_name']} {$user_data['last_name'][0]}";?></h3>
               <h4 class="job-title-prof"> <?php if ($user_data['sub_header'] == Null) {
                echo "Job Title";}
                else{
                    echo "{$user_data['sub_header']}";}
                ?></h4>
               <h4 style="color: white;"> Languages</h4>
        <span class="langauge-box-scroller">
          
            <?php
            component_language_box($user_data['python'], $user_data['C'], $user_data['C_plus_plus'], $user_data['java'], $user_data['html'], $user_data['css'], $user_data['php'], $user_data['kotlin'], $user_data['C_sharp'], $user_data['swift'], $user_data['ruby'], $user_data);
      ?>
  </span>
```

When the same code is placed in a function so that multiple cards can be generated and shown on one page the media elements show up on the page as opposed to inside the box as shown by the first part of the code.

```
$FirstName = $row['first_name'];
     $LastName = $row['last_name'][0];
     $sub_header = $row['sub_header'];
     $about = $row['about'];
     $img = $row['img'];
     $userid = $row['user_id'];
     $languagebox = component_language_box($row['python'], $row['C'], $row['C_plus_plus'], $row['java'], $row['html'], $row['css'], $row['php'], $row['kotlin'], $row['C_sharp'], $row['swift'], $row['ruby'], $row);

$element = 
    "
    <div class=\"grid-item\" style=\"border-radius: 6px\"; height=\"auto\";>

               <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
                    <div class=\"card shadow\">
                    </div>
          <div class=\"card-body\">
               <img class=\"profile-img\" src=\"pictures\profilepictures\profile.".$userid.".".$FirstName.".".$img."\", border=\"10\", width=\"250\" height=\"300\">
               <h3 class=\"card-title\">$FirstName $LastName</h3>
               <h4 class=\"job-title\" style=\"text-align: center;\"> $sub_header</h4>
               <span class=\"langauge-box-scroller\">$languagebox
          
      </span>
      <ul class=\"language-list\">
               <li class=\"social-item\" padding=\"50px\"><a href=\"#\"</a><img scr=\"https://via.placeholder.com/150\"</li>
          <li class=\"social-item\"><a href=\"#\" <img scr=\"https://via.placeholder.com/150\"></a></li>
          <li class=\"social-item\"><a href=\"#\"></a><img scr=\"https://via.placeholder.com/150\"</li> 
          </ul>

          <p class=\"card-text\">
               Example text$about
          </p>
          <h5>
               
               <span class=\"price\">$sub_header</span>
          </h5>
          <ul class=\"social-list\" list-style-type=\"none;\" display=\"flex;\" justify-content=\"center;\">
          <li class=\"social-item\" padding=\"50px;\"><a href=\"#\" <i class=\"fa-regular fa-heart\"></i></a></li>
          <li class=\"social-item\" padding=\"50px;\"><a href=\"#\" <i class=\"fa-regular fa-envelope\"></i></a></li>
          <li class=\"social-item\" padding=\"50px;\"><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa-solid fa-calendar\"></i></a></li> 
          </ul>
     </div>
```

Finally function to generate language box

```
function component_language_box($python, $C, $C_plus_plus, $java, $html, $css, $php, $kotlin, $C_sharp, $swift, $ruby, $row)
{

     $FirstName = $row['first_name'];
     $LastName = $row['last_name'][0];
     $sub_header = $row['sub_header'];
     $about = $row['about'];
     $img = $row['img'];
     $userid = $row['user_id'];
     "<span class=\"langauge-box-scroller\">";

     if ($python == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\Python-language.png\", border=\"5\">";

     }
     if ($C == 'True') {

          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\C.png\",alt=\"C no img\", border=\"5\">";
          
     }
     if ($C_plus_plus == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\C++.png\", alt=\"C_plus_plus no img\", border=\"5\">";
          
     }
     if ($java == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\java.png\"  alt=\"java no img\" border=\"5\"";
     }
     if ($html == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\html.jpg\", alt=\"html no img\", border=\"5\">" ;
     }
     if ($css == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\css.png\", alt=\"css no img\" border=\"5\">";
     }
     if ($php == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\php.png\", alt=\"php no img\" border=\"5\">";
     }
     if ($kotlin == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\kotlin.png\",  alt=\"kotlin no img\" border=\"5\" ";
     }
     if ($C_sharp == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\C#.png\", alt=\"C_sharp no img\" border=\"5\">";
     }
     if ($swift == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\swift.jpg\", alt=\"swift no img\" border=\"5\">";
     }
     if ($ruby == 'True') {
          echo "<img class=\"media-element\" src=\"pictures\codingthumbnails\picruby.png\" alt=\"ruby no img\" border=\"5\">";
     }
     "</span>";
     
    
     return;
```

Is there a particular reason this is happening or is there a better way I should be approaching this type of layout?
Two images attached of what I would like to see and is working with one code vs what is displaying with the other code.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

I have tried placing the language scroller box within different levels in the code (as in within the function or before the function) but in general don't understand why it works with one code and not the other.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXxmu.png  - code 1 working

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKb65.png  -  code 2 not working

Comment: `component_language_box` doesn't return anything, it `echo`s. Don't echo in functions, return the data, and `echo` the function call if you want it outputted. `return;` is a useless call currently, there's no need to ever do that as the function returns without that.

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/P0BKY for rough examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between PHP echo and PHP return in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387765/what-is-the-difference-between-php-echo-and-php-return-in-plain-english)

Comment: Specifically on that dup I'd say see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712648/3783243.

Comment: Understood. I should return the data and then echo the component_language_function. Is there a good way to return the element in the function when it contains the long list of  'if' statements?

Comment: Usually it is done by assigning to one variable `$data`, `$return`, etc. then at the end of function return that variable.

Comment: You also can use single quotes for encapsulation and eliminate all the backslashes/escaping here....`"<span class=\"langauge-box-scroller\">";`  for example can become `'<span class="langauge-box-scroller">';` ... also note that line isn't doing anything there. Maybe forgot an assignment?

Comment: Brilliant. Created a variable and appended to element after each if statement like so. Seems to work a charm. Thankyou
 $element = '<span class="langauge-box-scroller">';

     if ($python == 'True') {
           $element .= '<img class="media-element" src="pictures\codingthumbnails\Python-language.png, border=5">';